# Does anyone recognize this artist

Tags: translation, meaning

Does anyone recognize this artist[image]

Comment: I recognize the bird. It is a common house sparrow, "Passer domesticus" :)

Comment: Sparrows aren't white under their wings! But, the sparrow is a symbol for polygamy!

Comment: This is a Chinese sparrow!

Comment: @Pedroski I don' think you are born Chinese, base on your name :)  In this case, I think the sparrows that you are familiar with are the house sparrows, however, in China, the majority of sparrows are tree sparrows(Passer montanus) and they are white under their wings! Maybe off the topic but still good to know haha.

Comment: Haha! No, not Chinese, just a big fan of China! Where I live there are often flocks of sparrows on the ground. Under their wings does seem a bit greyer than the brown of their backs, but definitely not white! Maybe they just need washing?? :)

Comment: This picture was drawn by a Japanese man whose name is Utagawa Hiroshige